# Unable to remove NaN values from dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

When I am tring to predict the values for `z`, I am getting an error of 
"ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')." Am I making a mistake in line `data.fillna(0, inplace=True)` or is something else the problem?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Animkush/Desktop/train.csv")
data.replace("?", -99999, inplace=True)
data.drop(["Id"], 1, inplace=True)
data.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
data.fillna(0, inplace=True)

data1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Animkush/Desktop/test.csv")
data1.replace("?", -99999, inplace=True)
data1.drop(["Id"], 1, inplace=True)
data.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
data.fillna(0, inplace=True)

def handle_non_numerical_data(data):
    columns = data.columns.values
    for column in columns:
            text_digit_vals = {}
            def convert_to_int(val):
            return text_digit_vals[val]

        if data[column].dtype != np.int64 and data[column].dtype != np.float64:
        column_contents = data[column].values.tolist()
        unique_elements = set(column_contents)
        x = 0
        for unique in unique_elements:
            if unique not in text_digit_vals:
                text_digit_vals[unique] = x
                x += 1

        data[column] = list(map(convert_to_int, data[column]))

return data

data = handle_non_numerical_data(data)
data1 = handle_non_numerical_data(data1)

x = np.array(data.drop(["SalePrice"], 1))
y = np.array(data["SalePrice"])
z = np.array(data1)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(x, y,test_size=0.1)

clf = RandomForestClassifier()

clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)

print(clf.score(X_train, Y_train))

print(clf.predict(z))
```

Comment: can you add the data ?

Comment: Please include a stacktrace - to ensure the problem is happening where you/we expect it - and not actually somewhere else.

Comment: dataset - https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might have inf values, add following line

```
 data.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0, inplace=True)
```